# Auto update the user interface in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and not sure whether this question should be asked or not. Have searched many blogs but could not come to a conclusion. I have a rest API which is updating data continuously at server side, take for example stock data API. Now, if I use `$.get` of jquery or `fetch()` from react library it will update data only on initial page load. What I am looking for is as data change occurs from the API end simultaneously the change should be reflected in the user interface. Any help will be appreciated. 
As discussed with @Shubham Khatri please find te code below for react.

```
var StockData = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            stock: []
        };
      },

      componentDidMount: function() {
        this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, function (data) {     
           console.log(" Data value :"+data);
           var old = data.replace("//", "");   
           this.setState({   
                    stock: JSON.parse(old)   
               });

        }.bind(this));
        console.log(" Data value after bind  :"+this.state.stock);
      },

      componentWillUnmount: function() {
        this.serverRequest.abort();
      },

      render: function() {
         console.log(" Stock value :"+this.state.stock);
         return (
                React.createElement("div",null,
                        React.createElement("ul",null,
                            this.state.stock.map(function (listValue){
                                return React.createElement("li",null,listValue.t," ( ",listValue.e,"  ) -  "," Current Price :",listValue.l_cur,"    Date : ",listValue.lt
                                );
                            })
                        )
                    )
                );
            }
        });
```

Comment: one thing you can do is that after fetching data, put the data in the state array using `setState()` and render data from it. It will auto update you DOM on every change.

Comment: @Shubham Khatri Can you give any code example ?

Comment: yes if you provide me with your get request. and sample response

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri  have added the code, have a check.

Comment: this is what I suggested you to do. Is it not working. Whats the problem

Comment: As I mentioned, the data is only getting updated on initial page load and then it is the same and not updating. It is not synchronizing with the updated values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your get request is only getting fired on initial load. You need to fetch data regularly. Say if you want to fire the request initially and then after every 2 seconds then you can do something like this. I suppose this will solve your problem

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  this.startPolling();
},
componentWillUnmount: function() {
    if (this._timer) {
      clearInterval(this._timer);
      this._timer = null;
    }
},

startPolling: function() {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (!self.isMounted()) { return; } // abandon 
      self.poll(); // do it once and then start it up every 2 seconds
      self._timer = setInterval(self.poll.bind(self), 2000);
    }, 1000);
},

poll: function() {
    var self = this;
    $.get(this.props.source, function (data) {     
       console.log(" Data value :"+data);
       var old = data.replace("//", "");   
       self.setState({   
                stock: JSON.parse(old)   
           });

    }.bind(this));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On component mount call `loadDataFromServer()` at a set interval and update the components state. This will re-render the component with the updated state data.

```
    loadDataFromServer(component, apiUrl) {
        axios.get(apiUrl).then(function(res) {
            var dataList = res.data.list;
            component.setState({
                data : dataList
            });
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadDataFromServer(this, this.state.dataEndpointUrl);
        setInterval(this.loadDataFromServer.bind(null, this, this.state.dataEndpointUrl), this.state.pollInterval);
    }
```