# How does Pusher Chatkit update so fast? (with React JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pusher

I follow this tutorial 
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-build-a-react-js-chat-app-in-10-minutes-c9233794642b (or here the code https://scrimba.com/c/crVznf6)
and it is a realy nice app.

They use https://pusher.com/chatkit. I am just wondering how
fast the API update is. Immediately. Of course it possible
to ask a API with setInterval() every secound
([Auto update the user interface in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38473083/auto-update-the-user-interface-in-reactjs))
but it seems they use a different way to do this.

I realy would like to know more about this technology.
maybe someone has an idea how to do that with rest
and other external APIs. Thank you. (I am really a React beginner)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DevRel at Pusher here.

Chatkit subscriptions happen in instantaneously in realtime because it doesn't work on a standard request/response principle.

Instead, each client will hold a **persistent connection** to the Chatkit service - the way the JS library does it is either by opening a [WebSocket - a protocol and API in modern web browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Websockets_API), or a persistent HTTP connection and streaming data through it.

As the connection is already established, the server can just send new messages, presence updates, and typing indicators in realtime to all the connected users.